# how to move Files to a folder using mv in bash with condotions?

Tags: linux, bash

I was writing this code to organize my downloads folder so it wouldn't be messy. i want the files to be moved to their proper folder like for mp4 it should go to the Videos folder. but the code is not working

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ -d Videos/ ]] && [[ -d Compressed/ ]] && [[ -d Music/ ]] && [[ -d Pictures/ ]] && [[ -d Executables/ ]] && [[ -d Misc/ ]]
then
    #Compressed Files
    if [[ -f *.7z ]]
    then
        mv *.7z Compressed/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.rar ]]
    then
        mv *.rar Compressed/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.zx ]] 
    then
        mv *.xz Compressed/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.zip ]]
    then
        mv *.zip Compressed/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.gz ]]
    then
        mv *.gz Compressed/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.iso ]]
    then
        mv *.iso Compressed/
    fi
    #Videos
    
    if [[ -f *.mp4 ]]
    then
        mv *.mp4 Videos/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.mov ]]
    then
        mv *.mov Videos/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.wvm ]]
    then
        mv *.wvm Videos/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.mkv ]]
    then
        mv *.mkv Videos/
    fi

    #Musics
    if [[ -f *.mp3 ]]
    then
        mv *.mp3 Music/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.wav ]]
    then
        mv *.wav Music/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.ogg ]]
    then
        mv *.ogg Music/
    fi

    #Pictures
    if [[ -f *.png ]]
    then
        mv *.png Pictures/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.jpg ]]
    then
        mv *.jpg Pictures/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.jpeg ]]
    then
        mv *.jpeg Pictures/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.svg ]]
    then
        mv *.svg Pictures/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.webp ]]
    then
        mv *.webp Pictures/
    fi

    #documents
    if [[ -f *.doc ]]
    then
        mv *.doc Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.docx ]]
    then
        mv *.docx Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.pdf ]]
    then
        mv *.pdf Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.pptx ]]
    then
        mv *.pptx Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.ppt ]]
    then
        mv *.ppt Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.xls ]]
    then
        mv *.xls Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.xlsx ]]
    then
        mv *.xlsx Documents/
    fi

    #Executables
    if [[ -x *.64 ]]
    then
        mv *.64 Executables/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.deb ]]
    then
        mv *.deb Executables/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.rpm ]]
    then
        mv *.rpm Executables/
    fi

    #Misc FIles (Unknown file formats)

else
    echo "No Directories found"
    sleep 1
    echo "Creating Directories"
    mkdir Videos/ Compressed/ Music/ Pictures/ Executables/ Documents/ Misc/
    sleep 1
    echo "moving files"
    #Compressed Files
    if [[ -f *.7z ]]
    then
        mv *.7z Compressed/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.rar ]]
    then
        mv *.rar Compressed/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.zx ]] 
    then
        mv *.xz Compressed/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.zip ]]
    then
        mv *.zip Compressed/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.gz ]]
    then
        mv *.gz Compressed/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.iso ]]
    then
        mv *.iso Compressed/
    fi

    #Videos
    
    if [[ -f *.mp4 ]]
    then
        mv *.mp4 Videos/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.mov ]]
    then
        mv *.mov Videos/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.wvm ]]
    then
        mv *.wvm Videos/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.mkv ]]
    then
        mv *.mkv Videos/
    fi

    #Musics
    if [[ -f *.mp3 ]]
    then
        mv *.mp3 Music/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.wav ]]
    then
        mv *.wav Music/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.ogg ]]
    then
        mv *.ogg Music/
    fi

    #Pictures
    if [[ -f *.png ]]
    then
        mv *.png Pictures/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.jpg ]]
    then
        mv *.jpg Pictures/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.jpeg ]]
    then
        mv *.jpeg Pictures/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.svg ]]
    then
        mv *.svg Pictures/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.webp ]]
    then
        mv *.webp Pictures/
    fi

    #documents
    if [[ -f *.doc ]]
    then
        mv *.doc Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.docx ]]
    then
        mv *.docx Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.pdf ]]
    then
        mv *.pdf Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.pptx ]]
    then
        mv *.pptx Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.ppt ]]
    then
        mv *.ppt Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.xls ]]
    then
        mv *.xls Documents/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.xlsx ]]
    then
        mv *.xlsx Documents/
    fi

    #Executables
    if [[ -x *.64 ]]
    then
        mv *.64 Executables/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.deb ]]
    then
        mv *.deb Executables/
    fi

    if [[ -f *.rpm ]]
    then
        mv *.rpm Executables/
    fi

    #Mics FIles (Unknown file formats)
fi
```

I guess it's from 'if' statement but i don't know how to fix it because i'm quite new to bash. the mkdir is working but all of the "if [[ -f *.mp4 ]]" was not.

Comment: Welcome on SO. _the code is not working_ is not an accurate description of the problem. Please edit your question and explain accurately what happens. Alternately, you could take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at the [asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Note that creating the directories first (with `mkdir -p` to avoid errors in case they exist already) would significantly reduce the size of your script. Note also that repeating the very same piece of code or very similar pieces of code is frequently the sign that a much shorter, simpler, and more elegant solution probably exists (e.g., loops, functions...) and should be used.

Comment: You forgot to create `Documents/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filename expansion is not performed within the bash compund command `[[...]]`. So, for instance, `*.7z` in `[[ -f *.7z ]]` means literally a filename `*.7z`. That's why your script won't work. The script below may be what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p Videos Compressed Music Pictures Documents Executables Misc || exit

for f in ./*.{7z,rar,zx,zip,gz,iso}; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && mv "$f" Compressed
done

for f in ./*.{mp4,mov,wvm,mkv}; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && mv "$f" Videos
done

for f in ./*.{mp3,wav,ogg}; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && mv "$f" Music
done

for f in ./*.{png,jpg,jpeg,svg,webp}; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && mv "$f" Pictures
done

for f in ./*.{doc,docx,pdf,pptx,ppt,xls,xlsx}; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && mv "$f" Documents
done
```

Notice the use of `-p` option in `mkdir`. The missing directories will be created and existing directories will be ignored without an error by this option.

Comment: thanks this was the answer i was looking for